# How can I access POST data in CakePHP that do not follow the naming convention?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm experimenting with CakePHP and I'm just surprised by how hard is it to accomplish the very simple task of reading a POST parameter.

The problem is, I don't use a form to submit the data. I'm using CakePHP as an API for my application and the provided values do not follow the naming conventions, so when I do `pr($this->request->data)` it just returns empty.

Suppose that I have parameters such as `username` and `password` sent to my `/authenticate/login` action and I need to read them to be able to perform the login. I don't want to require the users to provide parameters with names like `data[Users][username]`.

I can't understand why CakePHP developers like to require you to do so to be able to access them in the application! Why making our lives harder and not just provide a simple function like `$this->input->post('username')`?

Comment: And yes, I have read [accessing-post-data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-post-data).. There is nothing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to stop you accessing the $_POST superglobal, your data will be in there.

However, I don't recommend you go down this path.  There's a reason that everyone recommends [Convention over Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html).  For example, if you want to enable the security component so that people can't tamper with your forms, then you'll have to go back to the way that CakePHP recommends.

I strongly recommend doing things the 'Cake way' for the moment, everything is a lot easier if you do things the way that CakePHP recommends, especially when you start creating sites are not just simple one-user test cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ben. The reason why I decided to use a framework in the first place was their automatic input escaping and XSS protection. For instance, Codeigniter provides access with `$this->input->post('username')` and does the security validation automatically. However if I switch to `$_POST`, I will lose that feature and it's no different from using simple PHP.

Comment: My point is that why CakePHP developers try to make you follow their naming conventions and just "ditch" you when you don't?

Comment: Never mind.. I had made a stupid mistake in submitting the data, and the problem was not CakePHP, but it was my REST Client... Now, I can read my inputs using `$this->request->data('username')` , and the security is enabled as well..